# add zip won't do anything

Tags: php, zip

I am trying to zip some folders with this function:

```
public function generate_zip($directory,$name_of_the_folder){
        $rootPath = realpath($directory);
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip->open('path/to/my/zip/compressed.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
        $zip->addFile($rootPath,$name_of_the_folder);
        $zip->close();
    }
```

This does literally nothing. I have already checked the permissions and they seem to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ZipArchive, you cannot add an empty directory using `ZipArchive::addFile()`. You have to use `ZipArchive::addEmptyDir()` .
For your case, I think what you want is [ZipArchive::addGlob()](http://php.net/manual/fr/ziparchive.addglob.php)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the function 'addFile' wants two filenames: the first is the path to the local file (which you want to add to the zip) and the second (optional) argument is how you want the file to appear inside the zip.

You have a variable '$name_of_the_folder'. Does that contain the right value?

Php.net documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php

Comment: Yes I have tried with and without this value and with different names to make sure this was not the problem.

Comment: What's the value of '$rootPath' after realpath?

Comment: Actually the same as $directory. I always use realpath to make sure I am using the correct directory. I have tried with $directory in  addFile as path directly but also without luck.